# How to make a sticky footer and header with a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a `UITableView` in the storyboard with also a header and a footer defined as can be seen in the picture.

[image: screenshot]

However, the header disappears when I move the cell (it seems the header is the top cell). Same thing with the footer. It appears after I have browsed through all cells.
I tried to move the header and the footer outside of the Cell hierarchy. But this resulted in being not visible any more.

How can I make the header and footer sticky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse the section header and footer with the table header and footer.

- The section header and footer, in a non-grouped table, are *pinned* to the top and bottom of the table while you scroll.
- But the table header and footer, as you rightly say, are sort of like cells: they are before the first section and after the last section, and they scroll with the table.

If that's not what you want — that is, if there is something you want to show above the table and below the table, all the time — then you need to put them above and below the table view as completely separate views:

```
thing above
table
thing below
```

Of course, if you do that, you can't use a UITableViewController. You'll have to have a normal view controller, with the table view as an *embedded* view and the table view controller as a *child* view controller.

Answer (score 0):

When using static `UITableView`s, you can't add custom views as header. You need to set the header and footer like this:

```
//Header
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    //return your custom view here
}

//Footer
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    //return your custom view here
}
```

You also have to specify the height of your header/footer:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    //return the height
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    //return the height
}
```