# Sticky footer with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

Need to achieve a sticky footer behaviour using `UIScrollView`, I actually want to replicate the behaviour of section footer view(red view) of `UITableView`. (please refer below **gif url**)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GiNb.jpg

I have tried using the below constraints, We need the `Bottom Container` to be sticky.(it have to behave like the red section footer in `https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GiNb.jpg` gif)

[image: Constraints]

Comment: why u have to put it inside scrollView ? y not out ???

Comment: You can achieve this effect by using a table view as explained in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551650/how-to-make-a-sticky-footer-and-header-with-a-tableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with two constraints.

**First constraint** Connected between your sticky view's top and the container's bottom. This constraint should be of type `less than or equal` (first item is the sticky view), with priority `required`. It will allow the content's bottom point to go below it but not above it.

**Second constraint** Connected between the sticky view's bottom and the scroll view container's **parent**'s bottom, or wherever you have connected your scroll view's bottom. This will anchor the sticky view to a point outside of the scroll view. Make it type `equal` and priority `high`. It will contend with the other constraint but will only win as long as the condition of the first is met.

You will, of course, also need to set up other constraints as usual for the sticky view; `width`, `height` and `x` position. Remember that scroll views are a bit special, so you cannot just tie the left and right edges to the scroll view's edges, you need a width and height also. If unsure, do like this with remaining constraints for the sticky view:

- Set the `height` to your desired height value
- Set the `width` to the scroll view's `width`
- Set leading and trailing to the scroll view

Comment: The view at the bottom of screen should be dragged up along with the top view(Container View), like red view is dragged up when table view has no more rows below `https://imgur.com/a/45Urz`